# Nlog web config - deployment to several environments: cannot create log file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logging, nlog

Greetings to everybody!

I've Nlog linked to my asp.net mvc project:

```
<nlog throwExceptions ="true" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlogproblems.txt" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- 
    See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
    for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
    -->
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="File" name="fileTarget"
            fileName="D:\Logs\healthycontributions\nlog\${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
            archiveFileName="D:\Logs\healthycontributions\nlog\${shortdate}_{###}.log"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence" archiveAboveSize="10485760" maxArchiveFiles="100" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="fileTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

When I run it locally I see the log file and everything is OK. But when I deploy it to another environment I don't see any log files. I've tried to change the log directory to one for which my site has for sure write permissions but still - I cannot see any log files in the folder. Can anyone suggest me what should I do/change? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone know the answer? I don't believe that nobody hasn't faced this issue

Comment: Could you try posting the contents of the internal log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try check your bin folder of your website. We are using Unity for DI and it was not finding the NLog.config in the application root. When we moved it into the bin folder it worked.

It probably runs locally because you have Copy Always on the NLog.config, but when you publish the website, the bin folder does not have the file.